# Inserindo dados de um datagridview c# em outro datagridview dando 2 cliques

Tags: c#

Estou criando um sistema de vendas. 
Na tela de vendas possuo 2 datagridview 
Sendo o  1º (pesquisa de produtos) onde recebo os dados da pesquisa do produto, e o 2º(produtos selecionados) será preenchido com os produtos selecionado no primeiro.

Quero que quando o usuário clicar duas vezes em cima da linha do produto o 2º datagridview seja preenchido com o produto selecionado, criando assim a lista de produtos que foram escolhidos pelo usuário.

Fiz o seguinte código:

```
 private void dataGridPesquisaProdutos_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        ProdutoColecao produtoColecao = new ProdutoColecao();
        Produto produtoSelecionado = (dataGridPesquisaProdutos.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as Produto);
        produtoColecao.Add(produtoSelecionado);

        dataGridProdutosSelecionado.DataSource = null;
        dataGridProdutosSelecionado.DataSource = produtoColecao;
        dataGridProdutosSelecionado.Update();
        dataGridProdutosSelecionado.Refresh();


    }
```

Porém não estou conseguindo preencher o segundo datagridview com mais de um produto, sempre substitui pelo ultimo que foi selecionado.

Answer (score 1):

Não consegue adicionar mais do que um produto porque de cada vez que evoca o evento de `DoubleClick` da célula está a criar uma nova instância do objeto `produtoColecao`.

Desta forma já deve conseguir:

```
ProdutoColecao produtoColecao = new ProdutoColecao();

private void dataGridPesquisaProdutos_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Produto produtoSelecionado = (dataGridPesquisaProdutos.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as Produto);

    if (!produtoColecao.Contains(produtoSelecionado))
        produtoColecao.Add(produtoSelecionado);

    dataGridProdutosSelecionado.DataSource = null;
    dataGridProdutosSelecionado.DataSource = produtoColecao;
    dataGridProdutosSelecionado.Update();
    dataGridProdutosSelecionado.Refresh();
}
```

Parte-se do princípio que a classe `ProdutoColecao` extende de uma lista.

Answer (score 1):

Acontece que toda vez que você cai nesse método você tem uma nova instância de `ProdutoColecao`, assim você não está persistindo os dados que ela já possuia.

A solução para o problema é você inicializar esse objeto fora do método e apenas utilizá-lo quando der o duplo clique:

```
public class Pagina
{
    ProdutoColecao produtoColecao = new ProdutoColecao();

    private void dataGridPesquisaProdutos_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Produto produtoSelecionado = (dataGridPesquisaProdutos.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as Produto);
        produtoColecao.Add(produtoSelecionado);

        dataGridProdutosSelecionado.DataSource = produtoColecao;
        dataGridProdutosSelecionado.Update();
        dataGridProdutosSelecionado.Refresh();
    }     
}
```